# How to set the gamma?

Tags: lcd, tft

I have a TFT 2.2 inch Display. like this:

[image: figure1]

Its controller is [ILI9341](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9341.pdf). I ported it to my MCU and everythings work fine. one of the most important things in using a display is [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). when you would use a display you have to adjust it because it effects on the brightness. I think I have to adjust the  Gamma of my display. the value that currently I use for Gamma is `0x01`. I think that's the default value. when I looked at the datasheet. unfortunately as I expected that's weird to me. :(

also I have searched for finding a solution but none of the results was good. I have converted some part of the datasheet to jpeg for you that are about Gamma. links:

[Image1](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/02/06/file-page211.jpg)
[Image2](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/02/06/file-page212.jpg)
[Image3](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/02/06/file-page213.jpg)
[Image4](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/02/06/file-page214.jpg)
[Image5](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2015/02/06/file-page215.jpg)

How can I adjust the Gamma with these datas?
there is an equation, When should I use it? how can I use it?
What's positive and negative Gamma?

**Added1:** For supply I use 5V for Vcc and 3.3V exactly.

**Added2:** two pictures of my LCD when show me `0x001F` (blue) color in 16bit (65,536 colors) mode.

[image: figure2]

[image: figure3]

Comment: Why not just try some of the values for + an - correction in section 14 of the doc you provided, and see what they do?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Umm...okay, but I'm curious to know more about Gamma.